# NodeJS [Error] - Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `worker_threads` in nodejs to read multiple files and process the rows to later insert into the database (using `oracle-db`).

Aproximately i work with more than one million rows and every file have more than 10,000 rows.

when i was trying to create the "binds" to insert into the database of every row field, while using `forEachAsyncParallel` or promises of every row in `.map` i got the following error:

**Error**

```
RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
    at Set.add (<anonymous>)
    at AsyncHook.init (internal/inspector_async_hook.js:23:25)
    at PromiseWrap.emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks.js:182:43)
    at /app/services/workers/PushMultiValueFile.worker.js:1:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /app/services/workers/PushMultiValueFile.worker.js:20:84
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /app/services/workers/PushMultiValueFile.worker.js:20:57
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at AssignKeysNameOnValues (/app/services/workers/PushMultiValueFile.worker.js:16:12)
RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
    at Set.add (<anonymous>)
    at AsyncHook.init (internal/inspector_async_hook.js:23:25)
    at PromiseWrap.emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks.js:182:43)
    at Promise.then (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

-----------------------

***Custom code to read error:***
[2021-03-10T19:34:47.331Z] 
{
  captured_at: 2021-03-10T19:34:47.000Z,
  messages: '"Error: Worker stopped with exit code 1"',
  stacktrace: '"Error: Error: Worker stopped with exit code 1\\n    at /app/services/oracle_database.js:434:36\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"',
  execution_detail_id: 1203
}
```

There is a way to find fix this?

**Map with Promises**

```
function AssignKeysNameOnValues(keys, values) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let result = {};
            if (Object.entries(keys).length > 0) {
                const promises = (Object.entries(keys)).map( async (item,index) => new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
                    try{
                        if ([(oracledb.DB_TYPE_NUMBER)].includes(item[1].type))  {
                            result[item[0]] = values[index] ? parseFloat(values[index]) : null;
                            resolve()
                        }
                        else {
                            result[item[0]] = values[index];
                            resolve()
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        // throw await logError(new Error(error),(workerData.executionID));
                        reject();
                    }
                  }));

                  Promise.all(promises)
                    .then(() => {
                      resolve(result);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      reject(err);
                    });
            }
            else {
                resolve();
            }
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

The parameters receive:

**Keys**:

```
{
  ARRANGEMENT_ID: {
    type: 2001,
    maxSize: 255,
  },
  OWNER: {
    type: 2001,
    maxSize: 255,
  },
  LINKED_APPL: {
    type: 2001,
    maxSize: 255,
  }
}
```

**Values**:

```
{
  "0": "ARR16@#$%3423C0",
  "1": "1",
  "2": "42"
}
```

---

Other type to iterate the same values but i got the same error.

**forEachAsyncParallel**

```
Array.prototype.forEachAsyncParallel = async function (fn) {
    await Promise.all(this.map(fn));
}
```

Versions:

- Node: v12.18.4
- Npm: 6.14.6

Comment: How are you calling the function? what data use for arguments?

Comment: @Clystian, i just call the function sending the parameters, the first one "keys" store the fields and their data type. And the second "values" store the field value.

In that function i only want to match the field with their respective field value.

 i update the question, look above.

Comment: A side comment about your goal: for performance make sure you are using `executeMany()`.  See [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution). I assume you are using node-oracledb.

Comment: @ChristopherJones sure ! I'm using `executeMany()` after I build all the binds of records. thanks. And yes, I'm using `node-oracledb`

Answer (score 1):

```
RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
```

The above error is caused when a Set or Map hitting the maximum limit of elements.
See reference: [Maximum number of entries in Node.js Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452896/maximum-number-of-entries-in-node-js-map/54466812#54466812)

If still run into the problem, you can try [`large-set`](https://github.com/aldipermanaetikaputra/large-set) and [`large-map`](https://github.com/aldipermanaetikaputra/large-map), a package that allows you to store and handle a large number of elements without worrying about the 16.777.216 (2^24) limit in a Set or Map by partitions into smaller, enabling it to store and access more elements than the built-in Set or Map.